# Chromecast on the Samsung Tab E doesn't connect

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

I’m using chromecast to cast info to the TV screen.
After the successful registration of the application and the chromecast device itself, I successfully got to connect to the TV and casted data using the phone with api 27. At the same time I could not connect to the TV via the tablet using the same application. The tablet have api 19 and I have installed non official Android with api 27 which wasn’t successful either.

Both the phone and the table are successfully casts everything using standard apps like Youtube and etc.

When I’m using the tablet the error happens when I call function CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.startService and it calls onRemoteDisplaySessionError. For a few second the TV screen becomes black but the tablet shows me a message that the connection is lost.

This is the log which I got:

> D/MainActivity: onRouteSelected D/Rasul: CreatedPresentation0
>
> V/MediaRouter: Dispatching route change: UserRouteInfo{ name=Bedroom TV, description=Chromecast, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Devices types=ROUTE_TYPE_USER  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_USER , presentationDisplay=null }
>
> V/MediaRouter: Dispatching route change: UserRouteInfo{ name=Bedroom TV, description=Chromecast, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Devices types=ROUTE_TYPE_USER  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_USER , presentationDisplay=null }
>
> V/MediaRouter: Dispatching route change: UserRouteInfo{ name=Bedroom TV, description=Chromecast, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Devices types=ROUTE_TYPE_USER  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_USER , presentationDisplay=null }
>
> V/MediaRouter: Dispatching route change: UserRouteInfo{ name=Bedroom TV, description=Chromecast, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Devices types=ROUTE_TYPE_USER  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_USER , presentationDisplay=null }
>
> V/MediaRouter: Dispatching route change: UserRouteInfo{ name=Bedroom TV, description=Chromecast, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Devices types=ROUTE_TYPE_USER  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_USER , presentationDisplay=null }
>
> Dispatching route change: UserRouteInfo{ name=Bedroom TV, description=Chromecast, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Devices types=ROUTE_TYPE_USER  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_USER , presentationDisplay=null } W/CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: [Instance: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$10@b44de89] ConnectionSuspended 1 I/MediaRouter: Unselecting the current route because it is no longer selectable: MediaRouter.RouteInfo{ uniqueId=com.google.android.gms/.cast.media.CastMediaRouteProviderService:1cc4d2c9976ead58a32b1075cdd51184, name=Bedroom TV, description=Chromecast, iconUri=null, enabled=true, connecting=false, connectionState=2, canDisconnect=false, playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, deviceType=1, volumeHandling=1, volume=20, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1, extras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=868], settingsIntent=null, providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }
>
> > E/CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: Connection was not successful\
> >
> > E/CAST: result - null
> >
> > E/CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: Unable to stop the remote display as the API client is not ready
>
> V/MediaRouter: Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Tablet, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=null types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null } V/MediaRouter: Dispatching route change: UserRouteInfo{ name=Bedroom TV, description=Chromecast, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Devices types=ROUTE_TYPE_USER  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_USER , presentationDisplay=null }
>
> Removing route: UserRouteInfo{ name=Bedroom TV, description=Chromecast, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Devices types=ROUTE_TYPE_USER  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_USER , presentationDisplay=null }

I don’t really know what to do next. Is it even possible?

Comment: it's just haw connect phone via chromecast. I know how it's done.
I need create app for tab that use chrome cast api.

Comment: Can you add any details like code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.